# Create a page that outputs XML using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I need to create a page that emits a valid XML, based on data from a list (for clarity, I want to created a customized RSS feed based on list contents).

I cannot create a custom application or a web part because of restrictive intranet environment. So the only tool available is SPD.

When I create a page, and then try to emit some xml using *DataView* web part (by specifying `<xsl:output method="xml"`, and removing all html code around it), SPD automatically adds html markup like

```
<head>
<meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full">
</head>
```

when I save the page. That prevents the output to be a valid XML.

So, does anyone know a way to **render output of DataView as XML using only SPD**?

N.B. I don't know if it matters, but "*Enable Detaching Pages from the Site Definition*" option is disabled at the farm level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Edit the page in SPD and test until ready (ignore the head section for now).
2. Export the page to your local machine.
3. Open page in notepad (or other text editor) and remove the head section that SPD added.
4. Go back to SPD and import the edited file (overwrite the existing one).
5. Hey presto!